# How can I write a Macro to sum a Column that has #N/A values in it?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to create a macro that sums a column that will always contain a few #N/A values, the number of cells in the column will change daily and so will the position of the #N/A values.

I also want to put the result in the first empty cell below that last value i.e. the first empty cell at the bottom of the column.

This is as far as I could get:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Total()
'
' Total Macro

Dim rg As Range

Dim Cell As Range, Target As Range

Set Target = Range("D65536").End(xlUp)
    For Each Cell In Target
    Cell.Errors(xlEvaluateToError).Ignore = True
Set rg = Range("D65536").End(xlUp)
    rg.Offset(1, 0).Value = "=sumif(D1:D100 " <> 0 & rg.Row & ")"
    Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True

Next

End Sub
```

Im using D1:D100 but only because 100 will cover the amount of cells in my Column. This is giving a strange result of more #N/As followed by a True. I dont think I should be trying to use a formula within the code.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is NOT `Write code for me` site. You need to show your effort and tell us where you are facing issue and we'll be happy to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would loop through and check if the value is numeric then add it to the total:

```
Sub mysum()
Dim lstRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet5") 'Change to your sheet

With ws
    lstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lstRow
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 4)) Then
            .Cells(lstRow + 1, 4) = .Cells(lstRow + 1, 4) + .Cells(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @MarkWMulholland please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SpecialCells():

```
Sub total()
    With Worksheets("SheetName") '<--| Change to your actual sheet name
        With .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
             .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).Offset(1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers))
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```